# ListView with headers and ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to achieve a view similar to this ((Sub)(Sub)Item names not being part of the view - they show how the source data is structured):
[image: UI Schema]

EDIT:
As per comment, I'm adding an example of how I want to render the data (2 items):
[image: UI Example (2 items)]

That is, I have bunch of **Item**s which I want to render in customized way. Those have **SubItem**s that start being part of the *grid* (possibly spanning multiple cells). And those have **SubSubItem**s with more data to put inside the *grid* (each on one row).

I want the data that belongs to a grid, to be aligned according to my **Column** headers.

I manged to make this work using a **ListBox** with **ItemTemplate** set to **DataTemplate** defined in resources. Going down 3 levels of hierarchy, using **Grid**s to layout the content. There were 2 issues with this:

- Aligning the data in grid with column headers. I managed to solve this using top level grid as column headers and IsSharedSizeScope/SharedSizeGroup. But it wasn't very nice solution and the alignment proved difficult to achieve.
- Drawing borders around cells - since it wasn't just one **Grid**, but multiple within each other, borders would not connect nicely or have different thickness. I didn't manage to solve this so far.

I tried using **ListView** instead of **ListBox**, with **GridViewColumn**, but that disabled the **ItemTemplate** rendering.
Is there a way to use both? Or some other way to add the Columns with their default nice style and on-the-fly re-sizing capabilities? What about the cell borders?

Or am I looking at it entirely wrong and I should use different approach altogether?

I did try using **DataGrid** but that seemed even worse approach.

Note: I need virtualization - working with lots of items.

Comment: I must not be visualizing what you're after correctly based on your mock. It looks like a job for DataGrid with grouping to me. :/

Comment: @ChrisW. added a pic that hopefully makes it more clear. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Still looks like a DataGrid with grouping...or I suppose you could also do ListView with grouping kind of like shown [here](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-grouping/)

Comment: @ChrisW. putting aside that I would need to somehow convert the source item into multiple items with some UID (to group it with it), how would I achieve the merged cell in SubItem Col1?